# The sum of subspaces of $V$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing each of the subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with subspaces $U_1,\ldots,U_k$. Then $U_1+\ldots+U_k$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing each of $U_1,\ldots,U_k$.

Here's my approach (using Einstein summation) where I have a doubt:

Let $v\in U_1+\ldots+U_k$. Then $v=u_1+\ldots+u_k$ which is a linear combination of elements from $U_1\cup\ldots\cup U_k$, which means $v\in\text{span}(U_1\cup\ldots\cup U_k)$.

Let $v\in\text{span}(U_1\cup\ldots\cup U_k)$. Then $v$ is a linear combination of vectors $u_{ij}$ from subspaces ($j$ subscript denotes which subspace that vector is from and $i$ runs over vectors from a particular subspace):
$$v=b^ja^iu_{ij}=b^jw_j$$ where $a^iu_{ij}=w_j$ lies in $U_j$ due to closure under linear combinations.

My doubt is that any linear combination can contain arbitrarily many terms. Is the above approach valid in the general sense?

Comment: Didn't you just show that you can rewrite the linear combination into one with at most $k$ terms? Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @Christian: There will be finite terms over the index $j$ for sure, but over $i$ there can be any number of terms. Maybe I'm overthinking.

Comment: I think the most important point is that linear combinations are *by definition* always finite sums. This means that each of your $w_j$ is a finite sum of elements of $U_j$. Now that you already found $v=\sum_{j=1}^{k} b^j w_j$ you wrote $v$ as an element of the sum of the subspaces.

Comment: @Christian: Ah yes you're right. Silly oversight on my part - it passed out of my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be any subspace of $V$ containing each of  $U_1,U_2,\cdots, U_k$. Then for any $u_i \in U_i~~~i=1, \cdots, k$, $u_1+u_2+\cdots+u_k \in W~~~(\because \textit{subspace})$ implying $U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_k \subseteq W$, hence $U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_k$ is the smallest.